# Ruby on rails installing error on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ubuntu

I just tried to install rails by this command:

`sudo gem install rails`

but error occurs like this:

`Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR: Error installing rails:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.`

`/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in 'require'
from extconf.rb:1:in '<main>'`

`Gem files will reamin installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/json-1.8.3/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out`

I tried several times reinstalling ruby and also tried`sudo apt-get update`

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just follow the below steps and you will be able to `install` rails easily on `ubuntu` :

First install `rvm` (I guess you have already installed) using the `command` :

```
$ \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

Then install Ruby :

```
$ rvm install ruby
$ rvm --default use ruby-2.2.3
```

Then install Node.js for rails :

```
$ sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

And lastly , install rails by :

```
$ > gem install rails
```

You can check the version of rails installed using :

```
$ > rails -v
```

I hope this helps.

**Update:**

As per `@Amit` sir's comment , We can use the below command which installs both , ruby and rails combined as :

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails
```

Comment: there is **poor man's** installer command which installs both ruby and rails `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails`.

Comment: @AmitPatel : Thank you sir , i have updated my answer adding the link provided by you .

Answer (score 0):

Rails 4.0 needs RubyGem version 2.0.3, update your `rubygem`

```
gem update --system 2.0.3
```