# How to handle(or update) ruby version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, rvm

I'm trying to use `nginx` to put my app on my domain. But while I'm doing I got this error.

```
   [ 2015-12-09 08:44:44.7819 23453/7f3b513b4700 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:794 ]: Disconnecting long-running connections for process 12443, application /home/ubuntu/bangcokelite/public
    App 13735 stderr: ruby-2.2.2 is not installed.
    App 13735 stdout: To install do: 'rvm install ruby-2.2.2'
    App 13735 stdout:
    App 13881 stdout:
```

So I followed recommendation, `rvm install ruby-2.2.2`, and got another error like

```
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
Found remote file https://rubies.travis-ci.org/ubuntu/14.04/x86_64/ruby-2.2.2.tar.bz2
Checking requirements for ubuntu.
Requirements installation successful.
ruby-2.2.2 - #configure
ruby-2.2.2 - #download
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0 23.3M    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0Warning: Failed to create the file bin-ruby-2.2.2.tar.bz2.part: Permission
Warning: denied
  0 23.3M    0 16384    0     0   9679      0  0:42:10  0:00:01  0:42:09  103k
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 16384)
There was an error(23).
Checking fallback: ftp://rubies.travis-ci.org/ubuntu/14.04/x86_64/ruby-2.2.2.tar.bz2?rvm=1.26.11
Checking fallback: http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/rubies.travis-ci.org/ubuntu/14.04/x86_64/ruby-2.2.2.tar.bz2?rvm=1.26.11
No fallback URL could be found, try increasing timeout with:

    echo "export rvm_max_time_flag=20" >> ~/.rvmrc

Downloading https://rubies.travis-ci.org/ubuntu/14.04/x86_64/ruby-2.2.2.tar.bz2 failed.
Mounting remote ruby failed with status 2, trying to compile.
Checking requirements for ubuntu.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.2.2 - #downloading ruby-2.2.2, this may take a while depending on your connection...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0Warning: Failed to create the file ruby-2.2.2.tar.bz2.part: Permission denied
  0 12.6M    0 13032    0     0   728k      0  0:00:17 --:--:--  0:00:17  748k
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 13032)
There was an error(23).
Checking fallback: http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.2/ruby-2.2.2.tar.bz2
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0Warning: Failed to create the file ruby-2.2.2.tar.bz2.part: Permission denied
  0 12.6M    0  1167    0     0  16099      0  0:13:47 --:--:--  0:13:47 16208
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 1167)
There was an error(23).
Failed download
There has been an error fetching the ruby interpreter. Halting the installation.
```

Actually I got

```
ruby-2.2.2 is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install ruby-2.2.2'
```

this error everytime when I run project from my Web IDE. However it didn't occur any problems, but right now I think I should fix it.
Any ideas about this problem? Thanks

edit from here------

I started my project from this [rails-devise](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-devise) and it is based on `ruby-2.2.2`. But my Web IDE is `ruby-2.2.1`.

Comment: refer to this question , you will be able solve your error. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33930368/ruby-on-rails-installing-error-on-ubuntu/33930487#33930487

Comment: I'm not sure it works, cause I already follow similar way to install my ruby.